# How to load ucrtbase.dll from the executable's directory?

Tags: dll, windows-10

I have a Chrome plugin that crashes in `ucrtbase.dll` on my Win10 laptop, but not on other Windows 10 machines. I noticed however that the build number of my ucrtbase.dll is older than on those other machines. So just to exclude my version of ucrtbase.dll to be at fault, I am trying to get the plugin (CiscoWebCommunicatorAddOn) to use a different version of ucrtbase.dll, but this does not seem to be working. No matter what I do, the Event Viewer is always stating this:

> Faulting module path: C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ucrtbase.dll

According to [this documentation from Microsoft](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2015/03/03/introducing-the-universal-crt/), it should be possible to load ucrtbase.dll from the application directory. So I downloaded [Windows 10 SDK](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk) and copied the x86 version of ucrtbase.dll and all related DLL's from `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Redist\ucrt` to the application folder: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Cisco Systems\Web Communicator`. And I rebooted my machine after copying the DLL's. Still, what I find in the Event Viewer is this:

```
Faulting application name: CiscoWebCommunicatorAddOn.exe, version: 0.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x587cf68e
Faulting module name: ucrtbase.dll, version: 10.0.10586.0, time stamp: 0x5632d166
Exception code: 0xc0000409
Fault offset: 0x0008468b
Faulting process id: 0x4b24
Faulting application start time: 0x01d299bef3e90377
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Cisco Systems\Web Communicator\CiscoWebCommunicatorAddOn.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ucrtbase.dll
Report Id: 3ef4c064-19c7-495d-9729-ff6bd8dcd77c
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

Comment: You are trying to shoot the messenger, it merely delivered the bad news.  Stack corruption is a serious bug, it isn't caused by ucrtbase.dll.  You need to repro this with a debugger attached so you can see a stack trace.

Comment: @HansPassant I am not shooting at it. As I said, I am just trying to exclude it. I know that the problem might be elsewhere. And I don't have the plugin's source code, so attaching a debugger to it won't help much. I did try WinDbg, but it did not give me much information.

Comment: 0xc0000409 = STATUS_STACK_BUFFER_OVERRUN this is a bug in the CiscoWebCommunicatorAddOn.exe. also update to version 1607 of Windows 10, you still seam to use 1511 from November 2015.

Comment: @magicandre1981 Is this CiscoWebCommunicatorAddOn bug documented somewhere? If I could show that to our client, they might be able get them to fix it. Our client as more leverage than we do. ;) I would love to be able to update my machine to see if it changes anything. Unfortunately, company policies are preventing me to do so. Well, in fact, I don't see any update for my machine using Windows Update. However, if I new which patch to download, I could probably install it myself.

Comment: I just learned from our client who got in touch with Cisco that they acknowledged a bug on Windows 10 on computers with touchscreens, and I have a Dell laptop with touchscreen.

Comment: ok. so now you know that it is a known bug. wait for an update